# How to selectively add port for a specific actuator url?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-actuator

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: "health, prometheus, metrics, asgHealth, slaFunc, slaAvail"
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled: true
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled: true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled: true
```

This is my actuator settings in application.yml. Now I know that if I want to expose the above actuator urls to a different port I do something like this

```
management.server.port : 9090
```

Now my question is how do I selectively expose few urls say /prometheus and /metrics on a
different port ?

Comment: you can set/configure/deactivate the port for the (complete) "(http)management server", but not "endpoint specific" (i.e. all endpoints will be exposed on the default/configured port). sorry.